# Scala : Break Inner Loop

Tags: scala

As stated, we can use break statement to terminate execution of inner loop in nestesd loop.

Why the below code doesn't print '2 3' in the output?. The inner loop starts the execution at 3 why not like '2 3' '3 1'.

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks._  
object MainObject {  
   def main(args: Array[String]) {  
        for(i <- 1 to 3){  
            breakable {   
                for(j <- 1 to 3){  
                    if(i == 2 & j == 2 )   
                       break  
                    println(i+" "+j)  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Output

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

Comment: `i == 2 & j == 2` => `i == 2 && j == 2`

Comment: First those aren't _loops_, those are syntactic sugar for calling `foreach` on some **Ranges**. Second,  please do not use the `break` _operator_ I do not even know why it exists, it is implemented using exceptions which is very inefficient, it is extremely imperative and it isn't at all clear. It would be better to just use plain `if` or guards inside the _for comprehension_. Or, my personal favourite, write this as a _tail-recursive_ function, which can be returned whenever you want.

Comment: Everyone wishes @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez left answers instead of comments. It was used in 2.12's TraversableLike, where there's a comment on TraversableOnce along the lines of, "I wasn't sure how that worked." Grep says it's not used in 2.13. Some folks like a soupcon of break and return every so often. For others, they are like grapefruit or broccoli. After a few minutes, I appreciate the OP's intuition that execution should continue from the breakable like a label. Maybe `breakable` is too close to `break label`. I think break is another showcase of "it's just library, not language keyword".

Answer (score 0):

The break will break the code when the value of i and j be equal to 2 and will not continue till the value of i changes.

Comment: A poor and misleading answer. Better answer: `j` exists inside the `breakable` block. So when the `break` is invoked `j` disappears along with its current value. Once you are outside of the `breakable` block then `i` is advanced to its next value and we step into the `breakable` block where `j` is created and initialized.